# String version of MongoDB WithID typescript generic

Tags: typescript, mongodb

The `WithId` generic that comes with Mongo's typescript library is highly useful in scenarios where you don't want to modify your existing interface/type for use with MongoDB such as:

```
export class TagsCl {
    private publicTags: Promise<Array<WithId<ProductTag>>>;
    private allTags: Promise<Array<WithId<ProductTag>>>;
    private tags: Collection<ProductTag>;
        constructor(){
            //...
        }
        //...
}
```

I'd like a very similar generic called `WithStrId` or `WithStringId` or whatever that accomplishes the same thing, but adds a field with `_id: string` instead to an existing type/interface, for use in the front-end. What's the easiest way to make such a generic?

The existing `WithId` looks a bit complicated

```
/** TypeScript Omit (Exclude to be specific) does not work for objects with an "any" indexed type, and breaks discriminated unions @public */
export declare type EnhancedOmit<TRecordOrUnion, KeyUnion> = string extends keyof TRecordOrUnion ? TRecordOrUnion : TRecordOrUnion extends any ? Pick<TRecordOrUnion, Exclude<keyof TRecordOrUnion, KeyUnion>> : never;
export declare type InferIdType<TSchema> = TSchema extends {
    _id: infer IdType;
} ? Record<any, never> extends IdType ? never : IdType : TSchema extends {
    _id?: infer IdType;
} ? unknown extends IdType ? ObjectId : IdType : ObjectId;

export declare type WithId<TSchema> = EnhancedOmit<TSchema, '_id'> & {
    _id: InferIdType<TSchema>;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried my luck with ChatGPT and it came up with with this:

```js
export type WithStringId<T> = T & {_id: string};
```

Which meets all my requirements

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
type WithStringId<Schema> = Schema extends {
  _id: string
} ? Schema : never
```

The `never` type will simply not be allowed by the compiler.

Comment: So this was causing an issue where references to results of this generic would return `Never`. I asked ChatGPT the same question and it came up with `export type WithStringId<T> = T & {_id: string};` which works great.

Answer (score 0):

I started with x0a's answer and it works well, but when I apply it to types that already have `_id: ObjectId` the resulting type of _id becomes the intersection `ObjectId & string`. Since I'm only going to use this type on the frontend I added an Omit to strip the _id type information before adding it back:

```
export type WithStringId<T> = Omit<T, '_id'> & { _id: string }
```

Now, the _id is strictly `string`.